# Desativar quebra de linha automática ao indentar código no PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Preciso retirar a quebra de linha automática ao indentar o código no PhpStorm.

Para ser mais resumido, retirar essa linha para o código ir até o final e não quebrar a linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Eu Achei isso, se seguir os passos abaixo pode desativar...

> Ativar quebra automatica de linha Quando a linha é muito longa, se
>   desejamos que ela se divida automaticamente em várias linhas (de
>   acordo com o tamanho da tela do editor).
>
> Procedimento
>
> File > Settings > Editor > General > Soft Wraps > ative o checkbox:
>   'Use soft wraps in editor'

Comment: Então assim não funciona, já tentei esse jeito!

Answer (score 0):

Olá, caso não encontrado a solução, eu fiz o seguinte:
Settings - Editor - Code Style - Hard wrap at "300".

Resolveu por enquanto, mas vou pesquisar uma solução mais adequada e se encontrar eu posto aqui.

Answer (score -1):

[![Olá! Será necessário desabilitar opção "Show hard wrap and visual guides(configured in Code Style options) em:

File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance

Espero ter ajuda a comunidade. abç]]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).